What even is this chess position? #2
Here comes a new retrograde chess puzzle! This one features a cute little maneuver at the end that I would like to share with you:
Can you determine the last eight moves made by Black?


(14+14), FEN: ?

Oh, right ...
Apparently, it happened again. Somehow, while exporting the diagram, the chess pieces must have been replaced by letters! (I should really look into this ...) Similarly to last time, the replacement happened in such a way that letter cases correspond to piece colours and letter types (regardless of cases) correspond to piece types. With that information, are you able to recover the position and solve the puzzle?
Please provide your reasoning in your answer! Have fun solving this :)

There are some fairly obvious observations we can make here:

 No trickery this time around; a must be pawns since every other letter is present on the back rank. Similarly, c is the only letter that each side possesses exactly one of, so it must be the king.


 This is enough to determine the colors. Assume capital letters represented black. In that case, at least three captures would be necessary to obtain pawns on f3 and h3- one to bring the h-pawn to the g-file to pass, and two to bring both subsequent g-pawns to the f- and h- file. But there are only two lowercase pieces missing. Therefore, capitals represent white (and I will be referring to the sides as white and black from now on).


 Let’s now take a look at e. At first glance, it looks like it cannot be a rook or queen due to an illegal double check on a1. However, this is theoretically possible, due to the possibility of the last move being axb1+. That being said, axb1+ would require four captures: two to bring the d-pawn to b5 (since the a-pawn must remain on the a-file), one on h6, and one on b1. And white is only missing two pieces. Either way, we now know that white has four promoted pieces on the board, since they have nine pieces between D, B, and F, and one of them is the queen, so they can only have five natural pieces between them.


 Let’s assume e is the bishop. In that case, one bishop would have to be promoted since they’re both on light squares. However, in this scenario, black would have to promote on d1. White obtaining four promoted pieces in this scenario would require three captures- one to bring the b-pawn to the a- or c-file to promote, one to clear the d-file for the black pawn, and one to bring the e-pawn to d3 after black promotes. And Black is only be missing two pieces. So e must therefore be the knight.


 The same argument applies for any promoted black piece. Black cannot promote on any other square but d1, since it would require an extra capture that they don’t have access to. And d1 is out due to white needing too many captures. So black’s pieces are all natural. This means that b can’t be the queen.


 Let’s look at white’s bishops. White has three Bs on dark squares. White’s promoting squares are a8 (twice), d8, g8. Only one of these is a dark square. White cannot make a capture to promote on b8, f8 or h8 because one of white’s captures is the black d-pawn, and the other is to bring their b-pawn to the a-file. Therefore, it’s impossible for white to get three dark-squared bishops. B then can’t be the bishop, so it’s the rook.


 From here, the remaining pieces are clear. F can’t be the queen due to an illegal double check, so it’s the bishop. That leaves D to be the queen.

Let’s take a look at our final position.

 


 The last move for white obviously had to be -1. Bg1-h2+. At first, it seems impossible for black to have made a move in the previous position, but one is possible- -1…. Kh2-h1! This is possible since white’s previous move could have been -2. Bf2-g1+. Black needs another move in this position. The only solution seems to be -2….. Kh1-h2 after -3. Be1-f2+. Before that, Black’s only reasonable move is -3….. Kh2-h1 once again.


 

We appear to be stuck...

 and we would be, if it weren’t for -4. f2-f3+!!


 


 Black's last move from this position has to be -4..... Kh1-h2 again. White's queen couldn't have moved to c6 due to an impossible check from the bishop behind it, but a discovery sure could have happened: -5. Rf3-g3+! -5.... Kh1-h2 is forced, before which White can keep climbing the ladder: -6. Rf4-f3+ Kh2-h1 -7. Rf4-e4+ Kh1-h2 -8. Re4-e5+ Kh2-h1:


 

And now we're finally free:

 The e5-rook blocks the bishop on h8 from pinning the rook on g7 to the king. This means white's last move could have been to move the rook to g7, leaving black's previous move to be Bh8 (it could also have been Kh1 again.)

This is as far back as we can go; fortunately, it's exactly eight moves, which are:

 Kh2, Kh1, Kh2, Kh1, Kh2, Kh1, Kh2, Kh1. Truly some of the chess moves of all time.


You made a small oversight in setting up the final position (the two F's on the b-file are incorrect). This makes the final retrograde analysis a bit more involved, but you certainly are most of the way there :)

@TimSeifert D’oh, that’s embarrassing. I’ll fix it shortly.

@TimSeifert I believe it's been fixed.

Looks good now! This is a very good answer, thanks for taking the time :)

Am I missing something or is the final position not quite mate? (...Qxd1 f4+ Qf3 Qxf3#)

@Neil You're right, changed the # to a +
